# wget not saving multiple files as html

Tags: wget

I'm using

```
wget -i urllist.txt
```

All the urls are similarly named, so I get

```
index
index.1
index.2
index.3
```

Now, the names don't really matter to me, but is there some way I can get them to save as html? Instead, the extensions are 1, 2, 3, etc. Thanks.

Comment: First off, if I try your example, I'm getting `index.html`, `index.html.1` and so on. Second, are you on Windows or *nix?

Comment: Windows. I ended up using command prompt with `re *.* *.*.html`. I believe I'm not getting html because my links are just http://website.com/index. If I change the urls to http://website.com/index.html, then it saves as html.1.

Comment: Now it makes sense. I had the impression you'd just have hostnames like http://www.google.com, http://www.mozilla.com - which is what I tested with. Good you found a solution. Another possibility would be using a `FOR` to iterate over `urllist.txt` and invoke `wget` on each URL, giving an output filename with `-O`.

Comment: Ah, that could also work, but I'm not having any problems with the first method. Thanks again.